# Grouping same list value into one list value

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a question for grouping multiple list values into one values. For example I have this list

`data_list = [A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,C]`

then I want to make it into this

`data_list = [A, B, C]`

I have tried using `itertools.groupby` but I still cannot find my solution

```py
from itertools import groupby
data_list = [A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,C]

data_group = [(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(data_list)]
print(data_group)
```

the expected output is `data_group = [A, B, C]`

the actual result is `data_group = [(A, 2), (B, 3), (C, 4)]`

Comment: Basically you want to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method-1** --

you can also use `numpy` to get unique values:-

```
import numpy as np
data_list = np.array(['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'])
np.unique(data_list)
```

**Method-2**

You can use `set` to get unique values but in `set` result will not contain the same order.

```
new_list = list( set(data_list) )
new_list
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c"]
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
print(mylist)
```

you can also use OrderedDict to print it in order

```
from collections import OrderedDict
mylist =  ['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']
mylist = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(mylist))
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into sets?

you can first cast your original `data_list` into a set using `set(data_list)` then cast that again into a list.

```
data_list = [A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,C]

print(list(set(data_list)))

#OUTPUT:
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

What sets do is they only include unique values. Hence why when we run the `set()` function on your `data_list` var, we are left with only the unique values. Sets, in python, are signified by 'curly brackets' like those in dicts, `{ }`, but sets do not contain key:value pairs. The `list()` function casts your set as a list so you can treat it like a list in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to use python sets.
Per documentation, a part of the description is:

*"A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries."*

For example:

```
my_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
my_set = set(my_list)
print(my_set)
type(my_set)
```

Will output:

```
{1,2,3}
set
```

Mind that the resulting data type is `set`
So, if you want your result to be a list, you can cast it back into one:

```
unique_values = list(set(my_list))
```

And if you are planning to use that a lot in your code, a function would help:

```
def giveUnique(x):
    return list(set(x))

my_list = giveUnique(my_list)
```

This would change my_list with a list containing unique values

Answer (score 0):

Just adapt the `itertools.groupby` solution you have (found?) to only use the `key`:

```
>>> data_list = [A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C, C] # with A, B, C = "ABC"
>>> [(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(data_list)]
[('A', 2), ('B', 3), ('C', 4)]
>>> [key for key, group in groupby(data_list)]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```